# Redis conditional key notification

Tags: python, redis, notifications

I have a question about key events notifications from Redis listening by Python script.

I have several lists e.g. `list_no1, list_no2, ..., list_no10`. Some workers are pushing values into the lists.

I would like to be subscribed to `list_no2` and get the events in Python script **only** when `lpush` command on `list_no2` is invoked. The events from others lists should be ignored.

Is it possible to achieve that in Python with Redis?

Comment: Did you try to register for keyspace notifucations?
see: https://redis.io/topics/notifications

Comment: @GuyKorland, yes I am trying to use keyspace notifications implementing  line in code `pubsub.psubscribe(**{"__keyevent@0__:lpush": event_handler})` and wondering how to include in pattern `__keyevent@0__:lpush` additional information that I would like to observe `list_no2`.

Comment: did you try to register for `__keyspace` instead of `__keyevent` ? e.g.
`"__keyspace@0__:foo"`

Comment: If I use `"__keyspace@0__:list_no2"`, the listener catches events from all commands `lpop, lpush`, etc. affecting on `list_no2`.

Comment: right there you can either filter by command or by key

Comment: I have the same conclusion, I regret. May be Redis Strems will fit better to my use case.